# Do the rings of endomorphisms of a sheaf of modules form a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

See this link and the second comment to the question in particular: [Sheafs of abelian groups are the same as $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098613/531227)

To use the universal property of sheafification, I took the ring action as a map from the ring to the ring of endomorphisms of modules so as to use the universal property to get a map from the constant sheaf to the ring of endomorphisms of the sheaf of abelian groups.

But I can't prove that the endomorphism rings form a presheaf, let alone a sheaf.
I can't find the restriction maps.
Let $M$ be the sheaf of abelian groups. What would be the restriction map between 
$End(M(U))$ and $End(M(V))$ ?

Comment: For a sheaf of abelian groups $M$, there is an endomorphism sheaf of $M$ called $\mathcal{H}om(M,M)$. Over any open set $U$ the sections of this sheaf are the endomorphisms $\mathcal{H}om(M|_U,M|_U)$ of the restriction of the sheaf $M$ to $U$. See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294802/prove-that-sheaf-hom-is-a-sheaf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it.